# How can make all dictionaries inside list of dictionaries Default in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose i have the list of dictionaries like this

`dlist = [d1, d2, d3, d4]`
Now d1 inturn are the dictionaries of dictionaries like

`d1 = {'dd1':{'a':2. 'ddd1':'moredict'}}`

and inside can be many more dictionaries

Is there single line function which can convert all those dictionaries into deafult.

I want that if some `key` don't exist in any of child dict then it don't get key error.

EDIT:

```
#something like this , but i was looking for something buildin
def convert_dict(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            dictionary[key] = defaultdict(list, value)
            convert_dict(value)
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a recursive function that iterates through all the values, and converts them to a defaultdict if it is a dictionary?

Comment: That i can do but that looks buggy, i was thinking there may be something buildin , to solve my issue

Comment: Why does it look buggy?

Comment: @user2330497 could you please post your code?

Comment: into "default" what? You can replace the `__getitem__` within the dictionary? All variables in Python is objects, all objects have functions and you can modify them all.

Comment: the code you posted is not recursive

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee , i posted the code , i was thinking on that line but haven't used that

Comment: As @dbaupp stated, you'll need recursion if your dictionaries are nested. It helps if you write out all cases (two), and then find out how you should handle these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want that if some key don't exist in any of child dict then it don't
>   get key error.

Setting defaults is one option for this, or simply use `get`:

```
>>> d = {'key': 1}
>>> d['foo']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'foo'
>>> d.get('foo')
```

`get` will return `None` if a key doesn't exist, instead of raising `KeyError`. You can have it return a default value other than None, by passing it in:

```
>>> d.get('foo',{})
{}
```

Comment: i would prefer this for the time i don't get any other solution

Comment: `dict.setdefault` can also come in handy, if you're getting a mutable value and intend to mutate it: `d.setdefault("foo", []).append("bar")`

Answer (score 0):

As dbaupp already stated, would it not be better to write a recursive function instead? Because your dictionaries can be nested, I don't think there is a 'pretty' way to handle this otherwise.

```
def dict_to_ddict(d, defaultfunction):
    '''Convert (nested) dict to defaultdict'''
    ddict = defaultdict(defaultfunction)
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict): 
            ddict[k] = dict_to_ddict(v, defaultfunction)
        else:
            ddict[k] = v 
    return ddict
```

You can make this more compact, but that does not make it easier to read.